# The medians to the legs of isosceles triangle $ABC$ $(AB=BC)$ are perpendicular to each other. If $AC= 10$, find the area of the triangle.

Tags: geometry

The medians to the legs of isosceles triangle $ABC$ $(AB=BC)$ are perpendicular to each other. If $AC= 10$, find the area of the triangle.

I tried directly using Stewart's theorem here, but I don't know how to proceed nor if it's even the right approach.

Comment: Can you make an image please?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $AGC$ is an isosceles right-angled triangle, so $AG=CG=5\sqrt{2}$, $\Delta_{AGC}=25$.  Since the centroid $G$ divides the median in ratio $2:1$, $\Delta_{ABC}=3\Delta_{AGC}=75$.

Answer (score 0):

By the theorem of Pythagoras we get
$$(\frac{2}{3}s_c)^2+(\frac{1}{3}s_c)^2=\frac{c^2}{4}$$ where $$s_c^2=10^2+\frac{c^2}{4}-50$$
From here we get $$c=5\sqrt{10}$$ so $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10}$$ and the area is given by $$A=\frac{1}{2}(5\sqrt{10})^2\sin(180^{\circ}-2\alpha)$$
Can you finish?